# Detect unused CSS classes

Tags: css

I am lookg for a tool, plugin that is able to check on my web-deployment if in the css stylesheets is any class that is never used.

Everything I found was just interpreting the current displayed site, which therefor is still much work to check everything..

Comment: I'm using PhpStorm and it's doing it quite well.

Comment: I am searching for the same and just found this - CSSess bookmarklet http://razorfast.com/2010/11/21/announcing-cssess-the-bookmarklet-that-finds-unused-css-selectors/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dust-Me Selectors

Dust-Me Selectors is a Firefox extension (for v1.5 or later) that finds unused CSS selectors.

http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/dustmeselectors-2.2.zip

"It extracts all the selectors from all the stylesheets on the page you're viewing, then analyzes that page to see which of those selectors are not used. The data is then stored so that when testing subsequent pages, selectors can be crossed off the list as they're encountered."

Comment: The installation link: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/